# Can not access deleted foreign key record in trigger caused by cascade delete

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume the following tables and trigger exists:

```
CREATE TABLE "event"
(
    count           bigserial NOT NULL,
    action          text      NOT NULL,
    child_id        int       NOT NULL,
    persisted_field text      NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "event_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (count)
);

CREATE TABLE "parent_table"
(
    id               int PRIMARY KEY,
    field_to_persist text
);

CREATE TABLE "child_table"
(
    id        int PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id int,
    CONSTRAINT "child_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("parent_id") REFERENCES "parent_table" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_child_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
DECLARE
    v_id        int = coalesce(new.id, old.id);
    v_parent_id int = coalesce(new.parent_id, old.parent_id);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "event" ("action", "child_id", "persisted_field")
    VALUES (tg_op, v_id,
            (SELECT "parent_table"."field_to_persist" FROM "parent_table" WHERE "parent_table"."id" = v_parent_id));

    IF (tg_op = 'DELETE') THEN
        RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "on_change_add_change_event"
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
    ON "child_table"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "add_child_trigger"();
```

Execute the following statements:

```
INSERT INTO "parent_table" VALUES (1, 'something');
INSERT INTO "child_table" VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO "child_table" VALUES (2, 1);
DELETE FROM "child_table" WHERE "id" = 2;
DELETE FROM "parent_table" WHERE "id" = 1;
```

`event` table now contains the following records:

| count | action | child_id | persisted_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INSERT | 1 | something |
| 2 | INSERT | 2 | something |
| 3 | DELETE | 2 | something |
| 4 | DELETE | 1 | null |

However, there is the difference that `persisted_field` is null when deleting an entry of `child_table` on its own, compared to having it cascade deleted, by deleting the `parent_table` record that it points to. Why is `persisted_field` `null` in record with `count` 4 and how do i have to change the trigger for it to be `something`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is `persisted_field` `null` in record with `count` 4

The trigger fires `before delete on child_table` as expected, but in a cascade scenario that still happens *after* the `delete` on `parent_table` is completed, so this subquery finds nothing: [(demo)](https://dbfiddle.uk/aBGVQTDs)

```sql
(SELECT "parent_table"."field_to_persist" FROM "parent_table" 
 WHERE "parent_table"."id" = v_parent_id)
```

By the time you reach this statement, the `"parent_table"."id"` you probably wanted this to find, is already removed. [Chapter 39. Triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-datachanges.html):

> SQL commands executed in a row-level `BEFORE` trigger *will* see the effects of data changes for rows previously processed in the same outer command.

This concerns changes in the target table(s) as well as in any other object affected by the command, both directly and indirectly (through cascades and triggers, but also generated columns, rules or routine side-effects).

There's no way to defer the `parent_table` row deletion so that it could still be seen by the trigger firing right after that, when the `delete` cascades to the linked `child_table` row. From the [`CREATE TRIGGER` doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#SQL-CREATETRIGGER-NOTES):

> Row updates or deletions caused by foreign-key enforcement actions, such as `ON UPDATE CASCADE` or `ON DELETE SET NULL`, are treated as part of the SQL command that caused them (note that **such actions are never deferred**).

---

Second (part of the) question:

> how do i have to change the trigger for it to be `something`?

Create another one and attach it to `parent_table`. Make sure the one on `child_table` doesn't duplicate its work, ending up with one `event` entry from the `parent_table` trigger, then another one from the `child_table`.

A `before delete on "parent_table"` trigger could just create a temporary entry: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/O8euv7oX)

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_table_deletions
(LIKE "public"."parent_table" INCLUDING ALL);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_parent_trigger() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $add_parent_trigger$
BEGIN  INSERT INTO parent_table_deletions SELECT old.*;
       RETURN old;
END $add_parent_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "temporarily_persist_deleted_parent_table_row"
BEFORE DELETE ON "parent_table" FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "add_parent_trigger"();
```

And then the trigger on `child_table` can still see it, and use `coalesce()` with the result of its current lookup. After that, child trigger can wipe the temp entry

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_child_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$add_child_trigger$
DECLARE v_id        int = coalesce(new.id, old.id);
        v_parent_id int = coalesce(new.parent_id, old.parent_id);
BEGIN
    WITH wipe_recent_deletes AS (
        DELETE FROM "parent_table_deletions" AS o
        WHERE o."id" = v_parent_id
        RETURNING o."field_to_persist")
    INSERT INTO "event" ("action", "child_id", "persisted_field")
    VALUES (tg_op, v_id,coalesce(
                           (SELECT c."field_to_persist"
                            FROM "parent_table" AS c
                            WHERE c."id" = v_parent_id)
                          ,(SELECT "field_to_persist" FROM wipe_recent_deletes) 
                        ) 
            );
    RETURN coalesce(NEW,OLD);
END $add_child_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You might also want to consider adding [`ON UPDATE CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-REFERENCES) to `child_parent_id_fkey` to get that case covered. Otherwise a change to `parent_table.id` throws an error: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0hYP-LIX)

```
ERROR:  update or delete on table "parent_table" violates foreign key constraint "child_parent_id_fkey" on table "child_table"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "child_table".
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer and solution. I did hope that there was an "easier" way, but this is a decent solution nevertheless. The `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not required in my case, because `parent_table.id` will never change (by design). Please correct me i'm wrong.

Comment: I've attached a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/0hYP-LIX) showing that there's nothing preventing that from happening. You could
`create function prevent_update() returns trigger as $$ begin return null; end$$ language plpgsql; create trigger t_prevent_update before update on parent_table for each row execute procedure prevent_update();` to quietly abort updates on `parent_table`: [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/aDU5MPo3). Or [`revoke`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html) permission to do so from adequate users.